# Does SignalR have UDP protocol to communicate?

Tags: udp, signalr

I have an application which uses `SignalR` and some how my clients can't connect to the application through TCP protocol.

The question is what protocol `SignalR` uses for Hub Connection? if it's TCP then can i make it UDP protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR uses Websockets to communicate between the clients and the server.

If for some reason Websockets are not available, then it will fall back to other transport mechanisms.

As far as I know, by default, all standard transport mechanisms are via HTTP, so unless you can provide specific code for client and server I am not sure we xan be of much help.

Anyway, [check the official documentation for a full list of used transports and fallback.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Hope this helps.

Best of luck!